# Invoice with multiple Membership lines

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, invoice

I have CiviContribute Invoices working in CiviCRM 4.7 within Drupal 7, but as the documentation tells you to first View a Contribution and then either Print or Email the invoice, it seems that there can only be one Membership per Invoice.

Is it possible (or planned to be possible) to raise a multi-line Invoice?

I guess it would need to be something like "Print/Email Invoice for Contact's  Contributions that have a Status of "Pending".

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It is absolutely possible to have multiple line items on an invoice :)

This can be done by using "Price sets". More information about this can be found in the book here:

http://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.6/membership/membership-price-sets/

Once you have set up your price set, persons (either administrators or public users who purchases memberships on a contribution page) could purchase 2 memberships in the same transaction. Then 2 memberships will then be shown as separate line items on the invoice.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this suggestion, and apologies for my slow response.

From my readoing of Price Sets, they allow variations and addons for a single Membership.

Just to clarify, our requirement needs to allow a Contact to hold several unrelated Memberships, and for each Membership to appear as a separate Invoice Line.

As an example, say we have a Red, Green & Blue meeting room, each available for hire on a by-the-hour Membership basis. A Contact might take out a "two hours per month" Membership for the use of the Red room (say for a regular Association Committee Meeting) and a "one hour a day" Membership each for the Green & Blue rooms (for regular Membership Activity meetings).

Is it possible to combine these three unrelated Memberships in a single Invoice, as three separate lines? (Sorry if I'm overlooking how this would be achieved with Price Sets)

Thanks

Comment: by the way, I can definitely see how Price Sets could be used to include resources within each meeting room, such as Flip Board, Projector, etc.

Comment: As per SE guidance, please don't use an answer if you have questions on another answer, please comment on that answer instead. Or edit the original question.